# How to create custom shortcode for wordpress for products?

Tags: php, wordpress

i have a card design and is required to create ti as shortcode. But i dont know how can i do this. My card design is here: https://prnt.sc/ElzMofw8Mh-9  . I think shortcode should be php code. Can someone take an example?

Something like this:

```
[price_box title="Najili Badewannenkissen" patch="Bestes Preis-Leistungs-Verhältnis" price="27,99 €" size="43x41 cm" material="Weiches Hochwertiges Polyestergewebe" rating="5" link="amazon.com" image=“https://medrepublic.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Schlafposition6-e1670856393513.jpg“\]
• 4D-Air-Mesh-Technologie und weichem Stoff
• Optimale Unterstützung für Ihren Nacken und Kopf
• Sechs Saugnäpfe halten das Kissen in Position
• Kann problemlos in der Waschmaschine gewaschen werden
[/price_box]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This goes in the editor

[price_box title="Najili Badewannenkissen" patch="Bestes Preis-Leistungs-Verhältnis" price="27,99 €" size="43x41 cm" material="Weiches Hochwertiges Polyestergewebe" rating="5" link="amazon.com" image="https://medrepublic.de/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Schlafposition6-e1670856393513.jpg"]

• 4D-Air-Mesh-Technologie und weichem Stoff
• Optimale Unterstützung für Ihren Nacken und Kopf
• Sechs Saugnäpfe halten das Kissen in Position
• Kann problemlos in der Waschmaschine gewaschen werden

[/price_box]

This goes in functions.php

```
function price_box_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'title' => '',
        'patch' => '',
        'price' => '',
        'size' => '',
        'material' => '',
        'rating' => null,
        'link' => '',
        'image' => ''
    ), $atts );
    
    $starImg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path d="M316.9 18C311.6 7 300.4 0 288.1 0s-23.4 7-28.8 18L195 150.3 51.4 171.5c-12 1.8-22 10.2-25.7 21.7s-.7 24.2 7.9 32.7L137.8 329 113.2 474.7c-2 12 3 24.2 12.9 31.3s23 8 33.8 2.3l128.3-68.5 128.3 68.5c10.8 5.7 23.9 4.9 33.8-2.3s14.9-19.3 12.9-31.3L438.5 329 542.7 225.9c8.6-8.5 11.7-21.2 7.9-32.7s-13.7-19.9-25.7-21.7L381.2 150.3 316.9 18z"/></svg>';
    ?>

    <div class="price-box">
        <div style="display:flex;">
            <div>
                <p><img src="logo-url-here" alt=""><?php echo $a['patch'] ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $a['title'] ?></p>
            </div>
            <img src="<?php echo $a['image'] ?>" alt="">
        </div>
        
        <p>Price: <?php echo $a['price'] ?></p>
        <p>Size: <?php echo $a['size'] ?></p>
        <p>Material: <?php echo $a['material'] ?></p>
        <p>Rating: <?php for($x=1; $x <= $a['rating']; $x++){ echo $starImg; } ?></p>
        
        <div style="display:flex;">
            <p>Highlights:</p>
            <div>
                <?php echo $content; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $a['link'] ?>">
                    <img src="amazon-logo-link" alt="">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php
}
add_shortcode( 'price_box', 'price_box_shortcode' );
```

Add all styles to style.css

Comment: THis is good but i canot get the logo on this shortcode

Comment: Just add the logo url there or if it's in a folder use a function <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/logo.jpg

Comment: Hello again @velikukova this shortcode now have some problems. It shows on all posts also on posts where is not included. And also shows on top of pages where i am on editor mode. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a shortcode on Wordpress is basically a PHP function.
If you don't already have a child theme, I advise to create one.

Next step is to create your PHP function in your functions.php file (inside your theme folder).

After that, you have to "register" / "add" you shortcode with this function : `add_shortcode('name_of_shortcode', 'function_name');`

Example : Create a shortcode that displays a simple Hello World

```
    <?php
function hello_world(){
    return "Hello World";
    }
    add_shortcode('hello', 'hello_world');
?>
```

Comment: This works, but i have to make a design like on the print screen. I does not know how can i do that. Any example for that? Maybe something closer to that design is my first time i do this and i am a bit later

Comment: You can start by implementing your design into a PHP function, by returning the HTML of your card

Comment: You meanto put html inside php like this `<?php  <div>...</div>  ?> and about css? Goes to css file i think?

Comment: can you pake a php like design for me please,i am trying but nothing working yet